# Not able to generate CSV file with php

Tags: php, csv, export-to-csv

I want to download csv file using php. Here is what i did

```
    $filename = $reportof . '.csv';

    header('Content-type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '";');
    $f = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    $delimiter = ";";

    fputcsv($f, array('ID', 'Name', 'Status', 'Date', 'Rank'));
    foreach ($Reports as $line) {
        fputcsv($f, $line, $delimiter);
    }
```

Here $Reports contain all data i want on CSV file.
I am getting this data in response when i check console->network.
But file is not getting downloaded.
Can any one suggest me where i went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to close the file pointer after you're done writing to it.

```
$filename = $reportof . '.csv';

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '";');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');

$f = fopen('php://output', 'w');
ob_clean();

$delimiter = ';';

fputcsv($f, array('ID', 'Name', 'Status', 'Date', 'Rank'));
foreach ($Reports as $line) {
    fputcsv($f, $line, $delimiter);
}

ob_flush();
fclose($f);
die();
```

### Edit:

Added `ob_clean()` and `ob_flush()` methods, this is just to make sure any output in you buffer is cleared, this can be skipped if nothing is written prior

### Edit 2:

Added some dummy data to test, this works.

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.csv";');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');

$f = fopen('php://output', 'w');

$delimiter = ';';

$rs = [
    [1, 'some name1', 'open', date('c'), 1],
    [2, 'some name2', 'closed', date('c'), 2],
    [3, 'some name3', 'open', date('c'), 3],
    [4, 'some name4', 'closed', date('c'), 4],
    [5, 'some name5', 'open', date('c'), 5],
];

fputcsv($f, array('ID', 'Name', 'Status', 'Date', 'Rank'));
foreach ($rs as $line) {
    fputcsv($f, $line, $delimiter);
}

fclose($f);
die();
```

This downloads the csv automatically:

[image: test.csv]

Comment: It returns same output as previous no CSV file downloaded.

Comment: @rohitraut I would check your code then, added (another) working example as edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening a new browser window with the URL, using `window.open`. The browser will probably not make the client open the screen through an AJAX request.
Another cause could be your browser trying to display the file in a viewer, which it is not able to do so. Try a different browser?

However, this is still guessing, as you see the contents in the network tab of the inspector and not show us how you call the script...